# How can i coloring Rubix Cube By three-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I want in a three-dimensional array, I just want to paint the cells of the array that are on the outside of the array, like the image below.

[image: Example of a Rubik's Cube where the cells inside the cube are 0 and not painted]

I want by function **color()** get an array (call by reference) change the outer Rubix of the array convert to 1 and interior Rubix convert to 0

[image: Send array to function color()]

i create function color() But it does not work Rubik's walls do not change

```
$matrix = [
      [
        [3, 5, 13, 56],
        [0, 1, 165, 1],
        [-8, 78, 5, 8],
        [6, 5, 23, 45]
    ],
    [
        [1, 17, 5, 3],
        [1, 5, 1, 65],
        [6, 5, 5, -4],
        [0, 4, 3, 90]
    ],
    [
        [9, 9, 8, 0],
        [3, 5, 4, 8],
        [0, 5, 3, 9],
        [1, 4, 5, 7]
    ]
];
function color(&$matrix){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matrix); ++$i) {
        echo 'layer ' . ($i + 1) . ':' . PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($matrix as $j) {
            if($i == 1){
                $y=0;
                foreach ($j as $k) {
                    if($y == 0 )
                            echo   $f = 1 . ' ';
                    elseif($y == 1)
                            echo   $f = 0 . ' ';
                    elseif($y == 2)  
                            echo   $f = 1 . ' ';         
                    $y++;   
                }
            }else{
                foreach ($j as $k) {
                    echo $k = 1 . ' ';
                }  
            }
            echo PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

how solving coloring Rubic Cube By three-dimensional array?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function color(&$ls) {
    foreach ($ls as $xs => $xl) {
        foreach ($xl as $ys => $yl) {
            foreach ($yl as $zs => $cell) {
                $ls[$xs][$ys][$zs] = (int)($xs == 0 || $xs == count($ls) - 1 || $ys == 0 || $ys == count($xl) - 1 or $zs == 0 or $zs == count($yl) - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```